# PHP json_decode returns int(1)

Tags: php

I'm having some trouble accessing a json string - [Demo Link](http://littleloans.co.za/test.php?idno=62393593366)

```
  //PHP CODE 
$json = curl_exec($ch); 
$json = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($json);

  // RESULTS
@{"error":"Bank account validation failed.","error_type":null,"code":400}
int(1)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: What does json returns before the json_decode call?

Comment: @ClaudioSantos - read the documentation for `curl_exec()`: http://php.net/curl_exec

Comment: Sorry, My bad. Try to echo the output of curl_exec(). What you're getting?

Comment: I imagine you're not setting `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` - curl_exec just returns true or false unless that's set to true, which would end up as a 1 after `json_decode`

Answer (score 3):

curl_exec($ch)

> Returns TRUE on success or FALSE on failure. However, if the
>   CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER option is set, it will return the result on
>   success, FALSE on failure.

Comment: Why the hostility? You could simply have referenced that explanation and given a short code snippet showing how to do it.

Comment: Agreed with @Yoshi. Removed the bomb at the end.